# Create an array inside for loop javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, html

I am trying to create a dataset pattern like this from the rest service in my angular application.

**Example:**

```
$scope.chartSeries = [
  {"name": "Google", "data": [100, 200, 400, 700, 300]},
  {"name": "Yahoo", "data": [300, 100, null, 500, 200]},
  {"name": "Facebook", "data": [500, 200, 200, 300, 500] },
  {"name": "Microsoft", "data": [100, 100, 200, 300, 200] }
];
```

Right now this is my code to build a similar pattern ,

```
 if (datai){ 
    $rootScope.DashboardData =[];
    $rootScope.DashboardData = datai;
    var _fieldData = [];
    widget.chartConfig.series  = [];
    widget.chartConfig.series  = 
    $rootScope.DashboardData.map(function(elm) {
        return { 
            name: elm[widget.seriesname], 
            data:_fieldData.push(elm[widget.dataname])
        };
    });
 }
```

Problem is data field is not creating an array. This is the final output which the above code generates.

```
 [{"name": "Google", "data": 1}];
```

Comment: you are assigning nothing to data. is a typo ?

Comment: Can you explain little more details about your problem? Where is your for loop?

Comment: @levi it was not aligned properly, now you can see

Comment: @RameshRajendran Loop means array.map function, i use this to rename the key inside an array

Comment: should be like `$rootScope.DashboardData.map(function(elm) {
   _fieldData.push(elm[widget.dataname])
    return {
        name: elm[widget.seriesname],
        data: _fieldData
    };
});
}`

Comment: That means `_fieldData.push(elm[widget.dataname])` this value is a array. but you did't map tha value in here. does make sense?

Comment: @RameshRajendran yes you are right

Comment: sorry guys, i did it in c# way. now got it! thanks @pankajparkar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning `_fieldData.push(elm[widget.dataname])` to `data` and `.push()` method returns the new array length, so you need to push the element first and then assign the array itself.

```
_fieldData.push(elm[widget.dataname])
 return { name: elm[widget.seriesname], data:_fieldData};
      });
```

Answer (score 3):

push() returns the new array's length

```
$rootScope.DashboardData.map(function(elm) 
{
    var _fieldData = [];
    _fieldData.push(elm[widget.dataname]);
    return { name: elm[widget.seriesname], data: _fieldData };
});
```

or you can use concat()

```
return { name: elm[widget.seriesname], data: _fieldData.concat(elm[widget.dataname])};
```

Answer (score 1):

try this , You nee a loop for `dataname`

```
$rootScope.DashboardData.map(function(elm) 
{
   var _fieldData = [];
   for(var i=0;i<elm[widget.dataname.length;i++)
    {
      _fieldData.push(elm[widget.dataname][i]);
    }    
    return { name: elm[widget.seriesname], data: _fieldData
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Array `.push()` always returns an [new length of an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

You should push that variable into `_fieldData.push(elm[widget.dataname]);` then assign that variable late in data.

```
$rootScope.DashboardData.map(function(elm) 
{
    var _fieldData = [].push(elm[widget.dataname]);
    return { name: elm[widget.seriesname], data: _fieldData }
});
```